# iTunes not getting updated via App Store on OS X El Capitan

Tags: itunes, applications, mac-appstore, macos

I am running iTunes 12.2.2.25 on OS X El Capitan. App Store is showing me update to iTunes (12.3.1) but its not getting updated. Multiple times I have click "Update" button (link) near shown update but nothing happens.

Please help.

Comment: Sometimes the App Store app seems to have trouble keeping track of what to update. Have you tried signing out (`Store>Sign Out`) and signing in again?

Comment: @jaume yes, I have tried signing out and signing in back, but it didn't help. Problem still persists.

Comment: I recently had a similar problem with Pages. The Update button didn't seem to work (it went gray for a moment and then nothing, no progress bar). But then, in the "Purchased" tab, I saw that it was indeed being downloaded. I guess it was just a rendering problem. Could that be your case? You could also try updating iTunes from the "Purchased" tab...